# Use Curl to get iCal link content

Tags: php, curl, icalendar

This was working until a few days ago. I have no idea what is causing the issue:

```
<?php    
$useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36';
$request_url = 'https://interface.casablanca.at/Export/ical.asmx/Get?Customer=A_6450_PEAK&q=QV82NDUwX1BFQUs6NQ';
$curl_timeout = 5; // seconds
$ch = curl_init();
if (strpos($request_url, 'https://') !== false) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $curl_timeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $curl_timeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, ''); // handle all encodings

$content =  curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {     
  echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch); 
}
curl_close($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

var_dump($info);
var_dump($content);
?>
```

I can GET that casablanca iCal link via Postman succesfully.
The Curl call works when i use a different iCal link on a different webserver.

Only when using that link simply nothing happens. There are other links to that casablanca server that also fail.

If i put the timeout on 10 seconds the error i get is:

> connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds

If i set the timeout on 120 seconds the same thing happens (after 120 seconds).

The both var_dump output nothing.

Could it be the webserver is blocked or something?

Comment: Nothing happens... so you mean `var_dump($info);
var_dump($content);` don't output anything? Are there any PHP errors in your logs? What HTTP response code does your PHP script return (assuming you're running this in a browser)? Try also adding `if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}` after `curl_exec` and see if there are any curl errors. You can also try to run cURL in verbose mode in case you get clues from that. We can't really investigate this much ourselves, you need to do that, since we can't access your environment.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, that code is working fine here (running via CLI)

Comment: Thanks. What happens if you simply don't set a timeout? Or set it to a much bigger value?

Comment: `The curl call works when i use a different link to a different iCal`...do you mean one from a different website entirely? Are there any others on the same "casblanca" site you can test? `Could it be the webserver is blocked or something?`...yes, if they've spotted that you're using too much of their bandwidth they might block you. Although an iCal is meant to be downloaded fairly frequently, so it would be a bit strange if they did that. If that's the cause, you'd have to contact the maintainers of the website.

Comment: This definitely sounds like a network block somewhere, not a programming problem.

Comment: Updates the question. Will try to see if a network issue can be tracked.

Comment: Can you call that URL alone in your browser? Does it download the .ics? Can you run the script via CLI?

Comment: Yes i can use the URL in a browser for download and also inside Postman.

Comment: So it was an network issue. Yesterday and today a major german hoster f***** up.